# Optimize rails IN query for millions of array IDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Wanted to get the users who are registered at specific account & its respective Outlet.

User & Outlet models doesn't have any association.

Outlet has_and_belongs_to_many accounts & vice versa

User contains the field outlet_code which is unique in outlet table

@account = Account.find(2546)

@outlet_ids = @account.outlets.map(&:id)      #-----It returns array like this [1,2,3....1032457] which is dynamic one

I have used this query which is not efficient => @users = User.where(:outlet_code => @outlet_ids)

Comment: Can you pls describe what you would like to achive and why you have an array of 1 million ids?

Comment: how this ids get calculated?? can you plz put here details

Comment: @outlet_ids = @account.outlets.map(&:id) #-------It returns all the outlet ids for that specific account whose count is more than 10 lac records

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is lazy loading and processing in batches.

Most efficient you can get in your case (assuming you then process the collection in any way) is to use [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each):

```
@users = User.where(id: [1,2,3....450000]).find_each.lazy
```

would return you the instance of lazy enumerator:

```
#<Enumerator::Lazy: ...>
```

Now you can just use it and iterate - `@users` will be loaded from the database on demand (lazily).

Answer (score 0):

Use find_each with batch size:-

```
@users = User.where(:id => [1,2,3....450000]).find_each(batch_size: 50 or no. of records you want to get in batch)
```

I will return records like:-

```
#<Enumerator: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [...]>
```

find_each with block:-

```
@users = User.where(:id => [1,2,3....450000]).find_each(batch_size: 50 ) do |user|
    # your code here
end
# User Load (0.7ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
#   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 50
# User Load (0.6ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
#   WHERE ("users"."id" > 50) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 50
# USer Load (0.3ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
#   WHERE ("users"."id" > 100) ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: How exactly this answer is new comparing to already given one?

Comment: Thanks, but using the concept of batch_size & find_each using ajax call , response gets time out because it is taking so much time to return the results.

Comment: Also, I got this error using batch processing 2015/12/05 07:29:05 [error]  upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client. I used this NGINX & MySql .